# D3.js does not display anything on the screen

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, geojson, topojson

I'm trying to use D3.js but I can not. I have the code below, but it does not print the map of Brazil. The screen does not show any errors, what could it be? My file "meso.json" is in topojSON format but it transforms the topojSON into GeoJson already in the d3.js code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D3.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var width = 900,
                height = 650;

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([55,10])
            .scale(750);

            var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

            queue()
            .defer(d3.json, "topo/meso.json")
            .await(ready);

            function ready(error, br_mesos){

                if(error) return console.error(error);

                var mesos = topojson.feature(br_mesos, br_mesos.objects.meso);

                svg.append("path")
                .datum(mesos)
                .attr('d', path)
                .attr('class', 'mesos');

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure if you tried it, but your center coordinates should probably be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Please change all your imports from **http to https** as some browsers block http.

**for eg:** change `<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>`
  to `<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>` and similarly for all.